# Write the co-ordinates of E such that the parallelogram ABCE is a rhombus.

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

I'm unsure how to do this and it's always in my exams. (The original shape was a triangle and E was originally not a point)

A:(1,0) B:(0,8) C(7,4)

Gradient of AC:2/3

AC equation:2x - 3y - 2 = 0

Coordinates of the midpoint D of AC: 4,2

- AC is perpendicular to BD
- ABC is an isosceles

Area of triangle = 26 u

Answer (score 1):

The diagonals of a rhombus bisect each other at right angles ([Proof](http://math.tutorvista.com/geometry/diagonals-of-a-rhombus.html))

If $O(p,q)$  is the midpoint of $AC, B E$

If $E(h,k)$  $$\dfrac{1+7}2=p=\dfrac{0+h}2$$  and  $$\dfrac{0+4}2=q=\dfrac{8+k}2$$